# Querying GZip compressed JSON S3 file in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a JSON data file stored in S3 that is GZip compressed, and I've created a Glue table to be able to query the data from Athena using the following configuration:

```
client = boto3.client('glue')
client.create_table(
    DatabaseName='data',
    TableInput={
        'Name': table_name,
        'StorageDescriptor': {
            'InputFormat': 'com.esri.json.hadoop.EnclosedEsriJsonInputFormat',
            'Location': source_location,
            'OutputFormat': 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat',
            'SerdeInfo': {
                'Parameters': {},
                'SerializationLibrary': 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.serde.EsriJsonSerDe'
            },
            'StoredAsSubDirectories': False,
            'Columns': columns,
            'Compressed': True,
        },
        'TableType': 'EXTERNAL_TABLE',
        'Parameters': {
            'classification': 'json'
        },
    }
)
```

When querying the data in Athena, I get the following error:

```
HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) 
is allowed between tokens at [Source: (org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
```

Naturally, creating a table with an uncompressed version of this data works as expected.

If it's helpful, the JSON data is [EsriJSON](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/iot/ingest/esrijson.htm) geospatial data (hence the serialization library and input format). Additionally, the file is stored in S3 with a `.gz` suffix and has the following metadata associated with the S3 object:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
```